# playwrigth- getAttribute() throwing error stating attribute not visible

Tags: typescript

i am new to playwright. below is the dom

```
<div class="rbc-event-content" title="trip27012024">
    <div class="custom-cal-event-wrap" data-timeframe="2024/01/28_10:00-2024/01/28_11:00">
```

i want to get the value of `data-timeframe`.
here is my code-

```
const tripsOnCalendar = this.page.locator(`.rbc-event-content[title="trip27012024"]`);
 const timeframeAttribute = await tripsOnCalendar
        .evaluate((node) => node.getAttribute("data-timeframe"));
```

when i do `console.log` of the `timeframeAttribute` , i get `Error: timeframeAttribute is not visible`

i also tried

```
const timeframeAttribute = await tripsOnCalendar
            .getAttribute("data-timeframe");
```

but no luck. any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
const timeframeAttribute = await tripsOnCalendar.locator(`[class="custom-cal-event-wrap"]`).getAttribute("data-timeframe");
```

worked.

Comment: Might be helpful to explain why the DOM selector was incorrect, leading to the undefined attribute.